# sorting sections using fetchedResultsController (Core Data) to populate my UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

Using Core Data, I have a fetchedResultsController to populate my UITableView.

I'd like to know how I can fix the order the sections are displayed, knowing that it is in no way related to the NSSortDescriptor I set to my fetchRequest?

(inside the sections they're sorted by date, but not the sections themselves)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two sort descriptors. First sort by the sections, then by the content of the sections.

Comment: first by content, then by section! Thanks!!

Comment: My bad! your answer is perfect. My error was not to create a NSMutable array* sortDescriptors. Sections then content then!